# Why do I get a black screen when I insert a subview?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, subview

Using the following code to insert a subview in my UIView I get presented with a black screen.  Can someone tell me why?

```
CJGBoardLabels* whiteLabels = [[CJGBoardLabels alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame 
    andOrientation:@"white" 
    andOrigin:self.boardOrigin 
    andSquareSize:_squareSize 
    andHorizontalOffset:_horizontalOffset 
    andVerticalOffset:_verticalOffset];

[self insertSubview:whiteLabels aboveSubview:self];
```

I get the same result with the following line too:

```
[self insertSubview:whiteLabels belowSubview:self];
```

Comment: check with `[self addSubView:whiteLabels];` assuming that self is a view.

Comment: Put a breakpoint before creating whiteLabels and log `self.frame`. What class is self?

Comment: Hmmm, well it's probably the wrong place to call this I guess.  `self.frame` is `CGRect` because I'm calling addSubview/insertSubview from the `drawRect` method of my parent view.  Is that the wrong place to call this?

Comment: You shouldn't be adding subviews in `drawRect:`, no. Also, `self` can't be a subview of `self` so trying to order based on that logic is flawed.

Comment: OK, so if I want to add a subview after the drawRect of the parent view is finished, where's the appropriate place to do so?

Comment: What is the trigger? User interaction? View created / displayed? Use the trigger, not the drawing operation.

Comment: It will be both.  So the subview will show labels that overlay its parent.  This will be shown by default on load or can be toggled on/off by user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add subviews in the `drawRect:` method. Instead, use the actual triggering method to add the subviews, and preferably get the controller to add the subviews (not the view itself). So, call `addSubview:` in the controllers `viewDidLoad` or an action method.